# Flutter Print UTF-8 (Vietnamese) on bluetooth thermal printer using "blue_thermal_printer 1.1.3"

Tags: flutter

I have a trouble, here is my code:

```
  if (isConnected) {
    final f = NumberFormat("#,###", "vi_VN");
    bluetooth.printCustom("CÔNG TY CỔ PHẦN", 3, 1);
  }
```

The printer worked properly but can not print UTF-8 Unicode characters:

```
The result: "C NG TY C  PH N"
```

I also found charset in plugin lib:

```
 Future<dynamic> printCustom(String message, int size, int align,
      {String? charset}) =>
  _channel.invokeMethod('printCustom', {
    'message': message,
    'size': size,
    'align': align,
    'charset': charset
  });
```

And replace charset by "UTF-8" but nothing change:

```
 Future<dynamic> printCustom(String message, int size, int align,
      {String? charset}) =>
  _channel.invokeMethod('printCustom', {
    'message': message,
    'size': size,
    'align': align,
    'charset': "UTF-8"
  });
```

I've tried with writeBytes but nothing change:

```
bluetooth.writeBytes(utf8.encode("CÔNG TY CỔ PHẦN ĐẦU TƯ XÂY DỰNG DƯƠNG KINH"));
```

Hope your help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In method bluetooth.writeBytes you must write bytes(List) your charset.
Like this:

```
 if (isConnected ?? false) {
      bluetooth.writeBytes(Uint8List.fromList([27, 116, 0]));
      bluetooth.printCustom(
            "Example",
            2,
            1,
            charset: 'Cp437',
          );
      bluetooth.paperCut();
 }
```

In [this](http://www.ekka.com.ua/files/doc/ma501_4421_00_rev14.pdf)  site you can look charsets and codes.
Look "ESC t n"

Read more about charsets.